# Why is the background of my legacy icon not transparent?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, icons

When I try to set the shape of the Legacy Icon in the Asset Studio to "None" it is still there.
If I do the same at Launcher Icons (legacy only) it is transparent.

How can I get a Icon that has a transparent background in API < 25 and a normal  Adaptive Icon in API > 25?

Answer (score -1):

[image]

modify `mipmap-anydpi-v25` like this